# How to wire a conditional block in option HTML element using vue 2

Tags: vuejs2

I'm new to vue and have a problem with a conditonal rendering (v-if) in an option element.
when i have an empty array i would like to show an disabled option otherwise it show me the countries. Like in this description https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html but unfortunately this is not working on an option HTML element. What i'm missing ?

```
new Vue({

  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
  
    selected: '',
    
    optionAvailable: true,
  
    countries: [
    
                //{ name: 'USA', population: '300M' }, 
                //{ name: 'Canada', population: '100M' }, 
                //{ name: 'Germany', population: '80M' },           
                
               ]
               
  },
  
  created() {
  
    if(!this.countries.length > 0) {
    
        return this.optionAvailable = false;
    
    }
    
    return true;
    
  },
  
  methods: {
  
    onChange(event) {
    
        this.selected = event.value;
    
    }
  
  }
  
})
```

html:

```
<div id="app">

  <select @change="onChange($event.target)">
  
    <option v-if="optionAvailable" v-for="(country,index) in countries" :value="country.population">{{ country.name }}</option>
    
    <option v-else disabled>-</option>
  
  </select>
  <br>
  
  <span>{{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

here jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/434002/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

template

```
<div id="app">
  <select @change="onChange($event.target)">
      <option v-if="countries.length" v-for="(country,index) in countries" :value="country.population">{{ country.name}}</option>
      <option v-else>----</option>
  </select>
  <span>{{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

script

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: '',
    optionAvailable: true,
    countries: [
            { name: 'USA', population: '300M' }, 
      { name: 'Canada', population: '100M' }, 
      { name: 'Germany', population: '80M' } ]    
    },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
        this.selected = event.value;
    }
  }
})
```

You don't need the created hook. You can tell `v-if` to look at the length of `countries` directly.

https://jsfiddle.net/z4mu8L9e/8/

Answer (score 0):

try this template

```
    <div id="app">

  <select @change="onChange($event.target)" :disabled="!countries.length">

    <option v-if="!countries.length" value="">No available countries</option>

    <option v-for="(country,index) in countries" :value="country.population">{{ country.name }}</option>

  </select>
  <br>

  <span>{{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

Script

```
   new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    selected: '',
    countries: []              
  },


  methods: {

    onChange(event) {

        this.selected = event.value;

    }

  }

})
```